# VBA find and findnext to paste values

Tags: vba, excel

I have this sheet where I want to use `Find` and `FindNext` to search for values on another sheet `BD` and copy them to my main sheet `Plan1` if the value on `alocacao` matches cells on `Column 5`.

I used to have 4 spaces with named ranges `tecnico1, tecnico2, tecnico3 and tecnico4` to paste the values and the code works fine.

This is how it looks:

[image]

And the BD sheet:

[image]

And this is the code:

```
Sub VerifProd_Click()
    Dim FoundCell As Range, FirstAddr As String, fnd As String, i As Long

    fnd = Sheets(1).Range("alocacao").Value

    Set FoundCell = Sheets("BD").Columns(5).Find(what:=fnd, _
        After:=Sheets("BD").Cells(Rows.Count, 5), Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If FoundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Do
        i = i + 1
        Sheets("Plan1").Range("tecnico" & i).Value = FoundCell.Offset(, -3).Value
        Sheets("Plan1").Range("upps0" & i).Value = FoundCell.Offset(, -1).Value

        Set FoundCell = Sheets("BD").Columns(5).FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
    Loop Until FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Or i >= 4
End Sub
```

However, now I realize that I'll need more fields because I maybe insert more than 4 `tecnicos` on an `alocacao`. So now this is how it looks:

[image]

And I just changed this part of the code:

```
If FoundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        Do
            i = i + 1
            Sheets("Plan1").Range("tecnico" & i).Value = FoundCell.Offset(, -3).Value
            Sheets("Plan1").Range("upps0" & i).Value = FoundCell.Offset(, -1).Value

            Set FoundCell = Sheets("BD").Columns(5).FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
        Loop Until FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Or i >= 10
```

So I was expecting that it just fills 4 fields as I still have only 4 matches, but I got this result:

[image]

As I'm new using Find and FindNext, I really don't know what I have to change to fill the cells with the matches only without repeating it.

Any suggestions will help! Maybe there is something I couldn't notice there.

Comment: You loop untill FoundCell.Address, but you never assign a value to that variable. Therefore it continues to loop until the second condition "i >= 10" is met.

Comment: @Luuklag that's true. I edited and now it's working, thank you!

Comment: your welcome. I started out the same way you are now. Just missing those small things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used the suggestion of @Luuklag and now it's working.

```
Sub VerifProd_Click()
    Dim FoundCell As Range, FirstAddr As String, fnd As String, i As Long

    fnd = Sheets(1).Range("alocacao").Value

    Set FoundCell = Sheets("BD").Columns(5).Find(what:=fnd, _
        After:=Sheets("BD").Cells(Rows.Count, 5), Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddr = FoundCell.Address
    End If
    If FoundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Do
        i = i + 1
        Sheets("Plan1").Range("tecnico" & i).Value = FoundCell.Offset(, -3).Value
        Sheets("Plan1").Range("upps0" & i).Value = FoundCell.Offset(, -1).Value

        Set FoundCell = Sheets("BD").Columns(5).FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
    Loop Until FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Or i >= 10
End Sub
```